# Injecting Carbon in Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, laravel, handlebars.js, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I have a Handlebars template which renders articles on my site by fetching data through an API. The API is returning a timestamp that I'd like to convert into a human readable format. I could format the timestamp through JS but I was wondering whether I could inject Carbon, `diffForHumans()` to be specific, to do that on the fly.

```
<script id="article-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="post-item">
        <div class="post-item__thumb">
            <img class="post-item__thumb__img" src="@{{ thumbnail_image }}"
                 alt="@{{ title }}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="post-item__content">
            <a class="post-item__title" href="@{{ url }}">@{{ title }}</a>
            <p class="post-item__meta">
                by <a href="#">@{{ author }}</a> on @{{ published_at }}
            </p>
            <p class="post-item__teaser">@{{ excerpt }}</p>
            <a class="post-item__read-full" href="@{{ url }}">Read full article</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Would it be possible to go about doing something like this?

```
    <p class="post-item__meta"> by <a href="#">@{{ author }}</a>
         on @{{ published_at }}{{ diffForHumans() }}
    </p>
```

Comment: Are your handlebars rendered by Laravel? or Rendered on the front end?

Comment: They are in a Blade view if that's what you're asking.